# Find $P[X\le 2, Y \le 2]$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-y}\hspace{.1cm}(1-e^{-x}) I_{(0,y]}\hspace{.1cm}(x) I_{[0,\infty)}\hspace{.1cm}(y) +e^{-x}\hspace{.1cm}(1-e^{-y}) I_{(0,x]}\hspace{.1cm}(y) I_{[0,\infty)}\hspace{.1cm}(x) $

Find $P[X\leqslant 2,Y\leqslant2]$.

the answer is marked as $1-4e^{-2}-e^{-4}$

but I am confused with the limits, someone could help me for the procedure

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is confusing about the limits?

Comment: In effect the density is $e^{-y}(1-e^{-x})$ when $0<x<y$ and is $e^{-x}(1-e^{-y})$ when $0<y<x$ and $0$ otherwise. The limits should now be easier and you can use symmetry to reduce the number of cacluations

Comment: my idea is to do the exercise like this $P[X⩽2,Y⩽2]= 1-P[X>2,Y>2]$ so my reasoning is to set limits in this way $ 1- (\int_{2}^{\infty} \int_{2}^{y}  e^{−y}(1−e^{−x}) \cdot dx dy + \int_{2}^{\infty} \int_{2}^{x}  e^{−x}(1−e^{−y}) \cdot dy dx $)   but I don't get the answer that I'm wrong with the limits !!!

Comment: The probability is simply  $2\times\iint_{0<y<x<2}e^{-x}(1-e^{-y})\,dx\,dy$ by symmetry. The rest should be straightforward.